# Charts.js mixed chart steppedLine, point not in the middle

Tags: chart.js

Have a nice day,
I would like the yellow line to draw from the vertical line to the vertical line (y-axis).
So that the yellow line does not start in the middle of the columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NCZB.jpg "situation picture"

```
   var barChartData = {
        labels: [{!$resSum['sektornazev']}],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Tolerované',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [{!$resSum['pocNO']}]
        }, {
            label: 'Archiv',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [{!$resSum['pocNU']}]
        }, {
            label: 'Netolerované',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [{!$resSum['pocND']}]
        },{
            label: 'Cíl',
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                            type: 'line',
                            fill: 'end',
                            steppedLine: 'after',
            stack: 'Stack 1',
            data: [{!$resSum['graflimit']}]

        }]

    }; 


  window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chartM').getContext('2d');
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Přehled všech akcí za období {!$obdobi['mesicName']} {!$obdobi['rok']}'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                                            }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                                                    ticks: {
                                                        stepSize: 1
                                                    }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

The desired result is shown in the enclosed image in the FINAL section.